# Create a framework that uses the Core Data model of the Project it is embedded in

Tags: ios, core-data, sdk, frameworks

**Scenario**

I am working on building a stand alone application that will also need to have parts of it included into a second application *that already exists*. This can be illustrated using the below:

- *`Project A`* - The existing application that utilizes **CoreData**.
- *`Project B`* - The application that is being built, also utilizes **CoreData**, but needs part of itself to be included and reused in `Project A`.

I have decided that the essential parts of `Project B` that need to be incorporated into `Project A` needs to be written as an SDK that can be used in both projects.

**Issue**

The SDK that I create from `Project B` needs to be able to utilize the CoreData `mom` that already exists in `Project A` **and** `Project B`.

**Question**

How should I architect this SDK to be able to utilize both `mom` in both projects?

*note: the entities that need to be accessed will be identical.*

Comment: Can you move the Core Data model to the framework and use it in both apps from there? I've done that with Cocoapods and it's worked out well.